# Probability of single entry originating from same individual

Tags: combinatorics

If I have a bag with n balls of k colors (equal number of each color), and I draw x balls (with replacement), what is the chance of getting two of the same color?

I tried to simplify but not sure if this is correct.

Balls of each color = (n/k), Chance of choosing ball of specific color = (n/k)/n = 1/k

Chance of two balls of same color, for each color = (1/k)^x * k

So is it (1/k)^x * k?

This assumes that there is an equal number of each color ball. What if the number of balls per color has a normal distribution? Just to have some context, in the actual data I have about 100M balls and 10-100K colors.

Comment: Assume I don't need to know the exact probability of getting two balls of the same color for given $x$, $k$ and $n$, but only to know for what sample sizes ($x$) I would get a lower than 5% chance of this happening, given $k$ and $n$. So, in the case of a normal distribution of balls per color, could I simplify by calculating the threshold of x for a higher value of $n/k$?

Answer (score 0):

Since you draw balls with replacement and you have the same number of balls for each color, $n$ is not relevant. You just need the probability of drawing a ball of a certain color (i.e., $1/k$). If $x > k$ the desired probability is obviously zero, so let assume $x \leq k$. 
The desired probability is equal to:
$1-Pr($all $x$ balls have different colors$)$. That is:
$$
1- \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^x \; \frac{k!}{(k-x)!},
$$ 
where ${\frac{1}{k}}^x$ is the probability of drawing a certain $x$-tuple of balls of different colors and $\frac{k!}{x!}$ is the number of possible such $x$-tuples.

If you have different number of balls for each color, $n$ becomes relevant and calculations are more complex: you should single out all possible different $x$-tuples, and for each, calculate the respective number of possible draws.

Comment: This formula doesn't work for the simple case of two balls of different colors and two draws. If the balls are red and blue, the draw options are red red, red blue, blue blue, blue red. So it should be a 0.5 chance of drawing two of the same color, but your answer gives 0.75

Comment: You are right: the previous formula $k!/x!$ was wrong . btw I can't help you with the asymptotic approximation you are looking for.